# how to use the wordpress site url and concatination for link href

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, content-management-system, laravel-blade

I work on a wordpress site and i have some trouble to generate the correct href link dynamically to link to different sites. My goal is to link to an id for a site section to scroll to, if you click a specific button/box. The box is wrapped inside an a tag and should get a dynamic link in the href to go to the specified section. The dynamic link should consist of the site url and the site/#id for the section to go to

here is what i have done so far!

My blade file looks like this:

```
<?php 
    $techboxes = $block->getBox();
    $mh_group = "technology-boxes-" . rand();
    global $wp;
    $site_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request));
?>
<div class="section section--margin-md">
    <div class="section__content">
        <div class="technology-teaser">
            <?php
            $title = $block->getTitle();
            $subtitle = $block->getSubtitle();
            $description = $block->getDescription();
            ?>
            <h2 class="technology-teaser__inner__title">{{$title}}</h2>
            <h3 class="technology-teaser__inner__subtitle">{{$subtitle}}</h3>
            <div class="technology-teaser__inner__description">{{$description}}</div>
        </div>

        <div class="technology-teaser__boxes">
            @foreach ($techboxes as $techbox)
            <?php 
            $title = $techbox['title'];
            $description = $techbox['description'];
            $link = $techbox['link'];
            $current_url = $site_url . "/technolgie";
            ?>
            <a href="{{$site_url}}" class="technology-teaser__boxes__box">
                <div class="technology-teaser__boxes__box__image bg-image" style="background-image: url({{$techbox['background']}})">
                </div>
                <div class="technology-teaser__boxes__box__text">
                    <div class="js-matchheight" data-mh="{{ $mh_group }}">
                        <h2 class="technology-teaser__boxes__box__text__title">{{$title}}</h2>

                        <div class="technology-teaser__boxes__box__text__description">
                            {{$description}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="technology-teaser__boxes__box__text__link btn btn--yellow">
                    <i class="btn__icon white-icon"></i>
                    <span class="btn__text">mehr erfahren</span>
                </div>
            </a>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I found

```
global $wp;
$site_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request));
```

which returns the right site url (i checked with var_dump).
Now i would like to add a specific site to the $site_url. I do this with:

```
$current_url = $site_url . "/technolgie";
```

here /technolgie is the site the where the link should go to and i will later ad another variable which holds the id of the section on the technolgie site.

If i var_dump $current_url it gives back a string with the right address. However it links not to the right page, it just reloads and do nothing. If i typ in the adress in my browser, it works fine. So im obviously missing something important here and someone of you is having a hint for me about this.

regards daniel.

Answer (score 0):

I got it and the answer is quite easy. Instead of using the sitename you would like to link to you need to concatinate the page id, like so:

```
$site_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request)) . '/' . '?p=44';
```

With this you can use $site_url inside your href and can link to the site.